# Creating Alerts with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create a warning but I couldn't do it according to this button. Can you create an alert based on this button?

```
   Button(action: {

                self.alertVisible = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Güncelle")
                    .frame(width:300 , height: 40)
                    .padding(10)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 30, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 45))
                    .foregroundColor(.init(red: 45 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 
        112 / 255))

            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var alertVisible = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button(action: {
                self.alertVisible = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Güncelle")
                    .frame(width:300 , height: 40)
                    .padding(10)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 30, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 45))
                    .foregroundColor(.init(red: 45 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue:
                                            112 / 255))
                
            })
            
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $alertVisible) {
            Alert(title: Text("Title"), message: Text("Message"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
        
    }
}
```